# Struts 2 framework demo

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Error log while deploying application on server.

```
Dec 19, 2013 5:26:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\MATLAB7\bin\win32;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\bin;.
    Dec 19, 2013 5:26:01 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:StrutsDemo' did not find a matching property.
    Dec 19, 2013 5:26:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Dec 19, 2013 5:26:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Dec 19, 2013 5:26:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 1834 ms
    Dec 19, 2013 5:26:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Dec 19, 2013 5:26:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
    Dec 19, 2013 5:26:02 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
    INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [231] milliseconds.
    Dec 19, 2013 5:26:04 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
    INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
    Dec 19, 2013 5:26:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
    SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:211)
        at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:278)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:383)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
        ... 22 more

    Dec 19, 2013 5:26:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Error filterStart
    Dec 19, 2013 5:26:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Context [/StrutsDemo] startup failed due to previous errors
    Dec 19, 2013 5:26:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Dec 19, 2013 5:26:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Dec 19, 2013 5:26:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 2483 ms
```

Please provide with some solution, Thanks in advance

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils` You must be missing apache-commons jar.

Comment: You are missing a dependency, transitive or otherwise.

Comment: missing jar file on your class path.

Comment: [click here for commons-lang3-3.1.jar](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.1/)  download. Add to class path.

Comment: Why grepCode -> maven -> commons-lang ? Just go on [comons-lang page](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) ;)

Comment: @AndreaLigios : thanks for new link. I usually download from grepCode. Next time I will recommend commons-lang page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing `commons-lang3-3.1.jar` (needed in Struts 2.3, not in lower versions).

You can (and should) use it along with `commons-lang-2.6.jar`, because their packages are different.

Look in the Apache documentation to see [all the Struts2 dependencies](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/dependencies.html).

[Download link](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) for both `commons-lang` versions.

Answer (score 3):

please make sure that your struts.xml action class mapping is correct

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: i think he did mistake in <action class="xyz"> mapping

Answer (score 1):

When using Struts 2.3 you need to add the both jar files **commons-lang3-3.2.jar**
and **commons-lang-2.4.jar**

**For Maven use the**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
  <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.24.1</version>
</dependency>
```

To download complete struts2 jars go to the link 
https://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts23241

**Below is the minimum smallest required set of jars for running the  Struts 2.3 web app**

[image]