# NoClassDefFoundError using struts 2

Tags: struts2

I am building an app using struts,i go through with the similar questions asked on StackOverflow but could not get the correct answer.

---

```
    Aug 25, 2014 5:15:41 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
Aug 25, 2014 5:15:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:211)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:234)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4775)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5452)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 20 more

Aug 25, 2014 5:15:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
```

This is a list of jar file am using

```
commons-fileupload-1.3.1
commons-io-2.2
commons-lang-2.4
commons-logging-1.1.3
commons-logging-api-1.1
freemarker-2.3.19
javassist-3.11.0.GA
ognl-3.0.6
struts2-core-2.3.16.3
xwork-core-2.3.16.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by the Exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils

You need to include the **commons-lang3** library together with the existing **commons-lang** one.

More info and download link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20682698/1654265).