# NoClassDefFoundError even after adding commons-lang3 library in Struts 2.3.24

Tags: java, ant, struts2, weblogic, weblogic9.x

I am working on a Struts 2 project.
 I have used `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` . 
 I am using `Eclipse IDE` and `Weblogic server 9.2`.
I have added the following libraries to the lib folder of the project :

- commons-collections-3.1.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
- commons-io-2.2.jar
- commons-lang-2.4.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
- freemarker-2.3.22.jar
- javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
- ognl-3.0.6.jar
- struts2-core-2.3.24.jar
- xwork-core-2.3.24.jar
- commons-lang3-3.2.jar

I have used ant build tool to build ear. 
There are no errors during compilation time but when I deploy the ear, I get the following error

```
SEVERE: Could not load user
defined filter in web.xml: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPreparecuteFilter.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
  at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.reg
XmlConfigurationProvider.java:213)
```

Even after adding `commons-lang3` jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the project, why am I getting exception?  
 Do I need to add any jar to weblogic server?

**Here I have included the commons-lang3-3.2.jar in the lib folder of the project so it is not a duplicate of the other question posted on stack overflow**

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError using struts 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485375/noclassdeffounderror-using-struts-2)

Comment: You probably need to add commons-lang also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485375/noclassdeffounderror-using-struts-2

Comment: Its not a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485375/noclassdeffounderror-using-struts-2 as in my case I have included commons-lang3 jar in my project.

Comment: Please anyone let me know whether Struts 2.3 jars are supported on Weblogic server 9.2

Comment: Check your archive. Is commons-lang3 still there?

Comment: I unzipped the ear file and found the jar - commons-lang3-3.2 in the lib folder of WEB-INF

Comment: Is commons-lang3-3.2 jar supported in java 1.5?

Comment: I finally found that commons-lang3-3.2 jar is not supported in java 1.5. Instead commons-lang3-3.0 jar can be used with java 1.5.

Comment: @Karthik: Post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found that commons-lang3-3.2 jar is not supported in java 1.5. Instead commons-lang3-3.0 jar can be used with java 1.5.